# What makes a Qt widget and its layout behave properly (in regard to its size)?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, resize, geometry

I'm having all sorts of size problems with Qt. I am creating my own widgets and using different layouts (generally, I need my own to make them work properly without spending hours on the "powerful" default layouts... which don't lay things out as intended.)

Once I'm done with a widget and its layout though, it doesn't work right. The size is never getting set properly unless I call `widget->resize(1, 1);` which finally forces a "resize" and makes the widget look correct (i.e. recompute the geometry.) Even the `updateGeometry()` call has no effect.

This is a dreadful problem when the `resize()` needs to be called on the parent widget (yuck!) and from what I'm reading should not be necessary were the layouts properly programmed.

Is there a sample that works and is not several thousand of lines long, or does Qt require several thousand lines to make anything work perfectly, even the simplest widget?

What are the minimal functions to be called to make a widget & its layout work at once?

Thank you.
Alexis

P.S. I tried to implement the `sizeHint()`, `minimumSize()`, `maximumSize()`, others that I'm missing? I was hoping that would be enough. Obviously, I also implement the `setGeometry()` on the layout to resize the children appropriately.

--- addition 1

There is a sample image with a layout that clearly isn't available as is in Qt. The positioning, functions, and colors of the different keys is XML driven and works for any keyboard in the world.

[image: On screen keyboard]

(note, this sample doesn't show the Enter key displayed on two rows and wider below than at the top; more or less, not doable at all with the regular layouts; of course, it works with my version.)

--- clarification

I'm not too sure how to describe the problem better. I was thinking to write a test widget next to see how I can reproduce the problem and then post that and eventually fix it. 8-)

The default layout function that the internal Qt layouts make use of require a lot of coding. I would like to avoid having to copy/paste all of that because for maintenance, it makes it close to impossible.

--- today's findings

As I needed to tweak one of the widgets, I decided to add a `VBoxLayout` and make it work.

I actually found the problem... One of the widgets in my tree is a `QScrollArea` and that `sizeHint()` returns (-1, -1). Not exactly what I'd expect but... whatever you put inside that widget has better know how to compute its width and height or else... it fails.

Looking at the code closely, I could actually compute the width by using the widest width found. Once I used that, the widget would appear (and it actually resizes itself as things change in the list, kinda cool.)

This being said, my earlier comment about having a tree of widgets that auto-resize themselves stands. From the root up to the parents of the leaves in your tree, all of those widgets will need a valid layout. Once I added one in the top widget it resized itself and its children properly (well... in my case up to the `QScrollArea`, the rest required a bottom to top resizing. Funny how that works!)

--- ah! ha! moment (or: what you find reading the implementation code!)

Today I bumped in another problem which just needed the correct call... I just couldn't find anything worth it in the documentation.

All the objects have a layout now, but a certain parent would not resize properly. Plain simple.

I had a call to the parent as following:

```
// changes to the children are changing the geometry
parentWidget()->updateGeometry();
```

Yeah. The docs says that's what you have to do. Nothing happens at all with that call. No idea what it's supposed to do, I did not look at that function. It never did anything for me anyway.

So... I looked at the layout to try to understand how it would send the info up/down. I did not see much except for one interesting comment:

```
// will trigger resize
```

This is said of the `SetFixedSize` mode. To reach that function you need to make the layout for update. Ah! Yes... the layout, not the parent widget... let's try that instead:

```
parentWidget()->layout()->update();
```

And voila! It resizes correctly in all cases I have. Quite incredible that the widget `updateGeometry()` doesn't trigger the same effect...

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish that the built-in layout system can't do for you?  It's difficult to answer a question that will be of any use to you when when it essentially boils down to "how do I make things work?"

Comment: For GUI/Layout quetions, including an annotated screen shot can help a lot. There's no shortage of people here that like to figure things out when they have solid info :)

Comment: if you don't have a problem your code then you can share it on www.ideone.com :D

Comment: @blueskin I cannot share _that code_, no... but was thinking to create a test case that fails so I can share that. Maybe it's because I am missing layouts at every levels... Only the lower widgets don't need a layout, and I guess that all the ancestors do need a layout if we want them to work.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's possible to do what you want it sounds like the problems you are having are because you're using Qt in a way that it's not meant to be used. Why do you need separate widgets for each key represented on the keyboard?

I see two options, both of which are better in some way:

1. Use [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsscene.html) and [QGraphicsView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsview.html).
2. A single custom widget that uses custom drawing to display the keyboard (and likely uses hover for hints).

The first option is probably better. Your keys could then be represented by [QGraphicsSimpleTextItem](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicssimpletextitem.html)'s or even a [QGraphicsSvgItem](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicssvgitem.html). It also provides a number of standard layouts or you could choose to [write your own layout](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicslayout.html#writing-a-custom-layout). By default you can use the [keyPressEvent](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#keyPressEvent) or [mouseReleaseEvent](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#mouseReleaseEvent) to respond to user interactions.

I'd highly recommend you take a look at the QGraphicsView [examples](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/examples-graphicsview.html) to get an idea what you can do.

If you go the second route you'll need to record the different key locations so you can respond accordingly as the user moves the mouse around, clicks, etc.

Comment: Would I have to render everything by hand in this case? With the PushButtons I get the rendering for free and the clicked() event...

Also my keyboard was an example, the problem I had was in a list where the layout chain breaks because of the QScrollArea (i.e. below the QScrollArea the size is not constrained in height, we want to resize the widget inside QScrollArea as tall as possible! But the QScrollArea has to be a sensible size for the purpose.)

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you with your immediate issue but I wanted to show you a keyboard I made using standard layouts and buttons. It's not perfect and it still won't help you with an enter key that spans two rows but it's not bad. It's resizable too by resizing the window, although I'm not sure if that will be apparent from the images below as SO may be scaling them. (you can view the actual images by opening them in their own tab)

[image]

[image]

Anyway, this was done using only Qt Designer with no manual coding. It consists of a top level vertical layout with 5 horizontal layouts in it. The buttons are then inserted into one of the 5 horizontal layouts. The size of the keys can be controlled by setting the horizontal and vertical size policies to "ignored" for most of the buttons and then horizontal "minimum" for buttons that you want to be wider. Things can be tweaked by setting min and max size restrictions to buttons. When resized, the buttons will not maintain their relative proportions though, that would probably take some custom programming.

The styling in your example could be approximated pretty well using css style sheets and background images. Still not a minor effort but you should be able to get most of the way there without custom layouts and buttons.

Comment: Yeah. There are many problems with QSS. It does cascading only on creation of the widgets. After that, it totally forgets about the parents. So that's really not that practical. This being said, I use the QSS for the colors, borders, font size, images...

Now, thinking about it, I'm wondering if my problem could actually be because all the ancestors do not include a layout. I think I read somewhere that for layouts to work well you need them everywhere.

Finally, in my case the keyboard can be switched to all sorts of layouts. For example, I could change it to a Kania or a French keyboard.